# Ant stops starting in Eclipse after editing ant file

Tags: eclipse, ant

When I edit my ant file, eclipse doesn't execute the ant correctly (does nothing). The file was auto generated from exporting a runnable jar file and I edited it afterwards. Here the ant file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project Elevox">
    <!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
    <!--define folder properties-->
    <property name="dir.buildfile" value="."/>
    <property name="dir.workspace" value="${dir.buildfile}/.."/>
    <property name="dir.jarfile" value="C:/Users/faust/Desktop/Elevox"/>
    <property name="dir.target" value="C:/Users/faust/Desktop/Elevox/elevox"/>
    <target name="create_run_jar">
        <copydir src="${dir.buildfile}/image" dest="${dir.target}/image"/>
        <copydir src="${dir.buildfile}/models" dest="${dir.target}/models"/>
        <copydir src="${dir.buildfile}/music" dest="${dir.target}/music"/>
        <copydir src="${dir.buildfile}/shader" dest="${dir.target}/shader"/>
        <jar destfile="${dir.jarfile}/Elevox.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="main.Elevox"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="${dir.buildfile}/bin"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${dir.buildfile}/lib/disruptor.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${dir.buildfile}/lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${dir.buildfile}/lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${dir.buildfile}/lib/lwjgl_util.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${dir.buildfile}/lib/lwjgl.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${dir.buildfile}/lib/PNGDecoder.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${dir.buildfile}/lib/slick-util.jar"/>
        </jar>
        <exec executable="cmd">
            <arg value="/c"/>
            <arg value="${dir.buildfile}/bundle.bat"/>
            <arg value="-p"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was a classpath error of a specific jar file, which was not well added to the classpath (path contained %20). After deleting it from the classpath and adding it manually again it worked.